# Jackson Deserializing Polymorphic Types: Handle errors due to misspelled classes

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism

Here is an example class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Cat.class),
    @Type(value = Dog.class)
})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class Pet {

/..../

}
```

I have two questions:

1. If we have a JSON with a misspelled type (Dogg) like following:  *{"type": "Dogg" }*

I will get the default *"Unable to read JSON"* exception.

How can I handle this to something custom as to say for example: *"Wrong type provided."*

2. If the type field is not provided in the JSON,  I am getting again *"Unable to read JSON"* exception.
   Is there a way to mark this field like for example *@NotEmpty* so the user will get a proper exception?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option you have is to preprocess the json before passing it to jackson.